# What steps are required to get DB2 working again after renaming the Windows XP system it was running on?

Tags: windows, db2

I think this is a fairly well known problem, but I haven't found a really solid solution to add to my toolbox.

Here's the sequence of steps that leads to the problem:

1. Install Windows (e.g., XP), naming the system `XXX`
2. Install DB2 and create some databases
3. Rename the system from `XXX` to `YYY` (via the System control panel's Computer Name tab
4. Reboot and find DB2 unable to start

How can I get DB2 up and running again without having to reinstall it and without having to rename the system back to `XXX`?

I did find a [blog post](http://vivekagarwal.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/how-do-you-rename-the-windows-machine-name-for-a-db2-v91x-database/) that hints at some registry values to tweak, but I'm hoping the SF community can come up with a solution in which I can have more confidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the official [instructions](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21258834) from IBM.